# Why do we need a temp variable to delete a node from a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I once ran into the problem where I did this:

`previous` is the previous node of current. `current` is the current node we are looking at.
This is so `prev.next` points to the element after current.

```
prev.next = current.next;
```

However, I forgot why this doesn't work and we have to do this instead:

```
Node temp = current.next;
prev.next = temp;
current = temp;
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `prev.next = current`.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Edited.

Comment: I think you're misremembering, or else it wasn't just a simple linked list. You don't need a temp var to remove a linked list node. You _would_ need one if you wanted to switch two nodes, maybe that's what you're remembering?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need a temp variable to delete a node from a linked list

Since when you remove reference from an element

You do NOT need temp variable as in code below to release link from current to the next.

```
prev.next = current.next;
current.next = null; // release this link
current = null; // optional
```

After removing we have: `current` is not referenced by previous node and `current.next` is `null`.

Because linkedList is a list where each element has a link to the next element (actually, it also has a link to the previous element).

Thus, it is very easy to remove an element from the list in comparison to ArrayList where elements are stored in array and removing an element means shifting every element in array after it.

> In computer science, a linked list is a data structure consisting of a group of nodes which together represent a sequence. Under the simplest form, each node is composed of a data and a reference (in other words, a link) to the next node in the sequence; more complex variants add additional links. This structure allows for efficient insertion or removal of elements from any position in the sequence.

Refer here [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Comment: Wait I'm not fully understanding. I never set `current.next = null`. Are you saying my first code still has `current.next` pointing to something?

Comment: Well, sure. If you never set `current.next = null` (or `=` anything else), why wouldn't it still point to whatever it pointed to before?

Comment: Doesn't the 2nd block of code also have current.next pointing to something, though?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: I've edited my asnwer. You do not need temp variable here. You  might need it if you had linked list with pointers to next and previous nodes (linked in both directions).

Comment: @Tala Even then you don't. `prev.next = current.next; current.next.next = prev` (with appropriate checking for the list's ends, depending on how you implement them). Also, there's not much to gain from `current.next = null`, since `current` will be up for GC in a moment anyway. (See the "explicit nulling" and "when good performance advice goes bad" sections [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html).)

Comment: @yshavit I see, the main benefit of explicit nulling here is code redability. Also, after removing an element you expect it to be completely removed and you might modify `current.next` in the same method when it is not GC'd yet

Answer (score 0):

We create Temp node in the delete method because we do not want to modify the start node pointer since we always need the start pointer of a linked list, so instead of modifying the start pointer we create a temporary pointer.